# SELECT * FROM table | Only getting the first row out of all

Tags: php, mysql

**SOLVED: Just use fetchAll instead of fetch**

I have a simple sql query that works in phpmyadmin, but in php I only get the first row returned. The table has a lot of rows, since it's a cities of the world table (around 44.000 rows).

```
function getAllCities(){
        include 'db.php';

        $response = json_decode('{"status":"error"}');

        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities_countries");
            $query->execute();

            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $response->status = "success";
            $response->cities = $result;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

This is what gets returned:

```
{
   status: "success",
   cities: {
      id: "1",
      name: "Bombuflat, India"
   }
}
```

As mentioned above, if I run the query in phpmyadmin, I get all the results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `fetch` method only returns one row. Use `fetchAll` instead.

Comment: It must be late, because I'm losing my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output all the results you should you use the fetchAll method

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Find more details and options in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php